# Why are commands not working for my discord.py bot?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

`

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

load_dotenv(".env")
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client.command()
async def unvc(ctx):
    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()

@client.command()
async def vc(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3')
        player = voice.play(source)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} has connected toDiscord!'.format(client))
    return await client.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="anime waifu simulator VR"))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

`

I am trying to use commands with my discord bot and it does nothing when I type them. It is still able to delete messages, so it isn't an issue with the connection to Discord.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Comment: It says AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you‘re using the olde 1.7.3 version of discord.py that is outdated at this time due to new required intents.

check your version with `pip show discord.py` and should upgrade to 2.x

then you also have to use the message intent if you‘re using the message command framework of discord.py

for that, go to the discord developer dashboard and activate the privileged intent „message“. after that, add the following to your code above your bot definition:

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.message_content = True
```

then pass the intents to the bot constructor with
`intents=intents`

(also, normally in discord.py programming, we do name `Bot` instances `bot` and only `Client` instances `client`)

Comment: When I try to do that it says this error: AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Comment: Did you check for your discord.py version?

Comment: It said that its 2.0.0

Comment: I went to the source for my import statement and saw that it said the version was 1.7.3. I deleted the package in the files and reinstalled it. Now it says 2.1.0. This seemed to have fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the bot listen to both, commands and messages. If you send a message, it will be read as a message and not like a command. For fixing that add:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx:Context):
    await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

Add this:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

This will add the intents to the bot. I've tried it out. That should work for you. You also have to enable intents in the bot settings in your discord developer portal.

Comment: If OP doesn't override the on_message handler then this isn't necessary in any way because it's the default implementation. The post doesn't show signs of an on_message so this won't fix (or break) anything. All it does is add 3 extra lines of code.