# I really need help, i cant run my discord bot for some reason. i was following a youtube video, and did everything they did. but it just doesnt work

Tags: python, discord.py

this is the code i am using, it works just fine for the guy in the youtube video. but it dOESNT WORK HERE

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="w!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Success: Bot Is Logged In")

client.run("(not showing for obvious reasons)")
```

when i run this code, i get a huge error in return.

```
2022-12-08 18:33:21 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tobia\OneDrive\Code\Python\Discord\Woof BOT\bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.run("MTA1MDQ0NDYyMjkzMDkxOTQ0NQ.GKzEfg.r-K4iQQeIABySOrOcH7AZ5Sr9sRacC_NpHaMuM")
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 746, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 672, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
```

i appreciate any help i can get

Comment: Did you read the error? The last line tells you exactly what the problem is and how to fix it, in plain English.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677) may help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the intents on the [bot page](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application as seen in [this image](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_images/discord_privileged_intents.png) (I don't have enough reputation to properly show the image, apologies).

#### Alternative:

If you don't need all the intents you can just use `discord.Intents.default()`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="w!", intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Success: Bot Is Logged In")

client.run("(not showing for obvious reasons)")
```