# Commands not working after updating to discord.py 2.0

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was trying to change my version from 1.7.3 to 2.0+ using pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py. Usually when I did this there would be an error about intents that would pop up, but instead there were no errors but it said:

```
discord.client logging in using static token
2022-12-20 12:34:14 INFO
discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID:6837cbf3ad28b9040ceb5e044dffe90f).
```

After that, any commands that I used didnt get responded to, as it worked perfectly fine in 1.7.3.

My code:

```
import discord, os, requests, json, random, time, datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db
import urllib
import asyncio
from discord import Member
from discord.ui import Select,Button,View

intents = discord.Intents.default()  
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="e!",
                   intents=intents)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
      

    if message.content.startswith('whats the meaning of life'):
        await message.channel.send(
            'The meaning of life is "freedom from suffering" through apatheia (Gr: απαθεια), that is, being objective and having "clear judgement", not indifference. - Wikipedia.'
        )
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send(
            'There, someone just explained your life. Kind of depressing, isnt it?'
        )
```

Comment: You don't appear to have the message content intent included. It needs to be enabled in the dev portal and set in your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Comment: I changed intents to discord.Intents.all and now it works

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is a little warning]

basically you don't have the correct intents to be able to send message with the bot
you need to have the discord.Intents.all()
and please don't use the time.sleep in an asynchronous function use asycio.sleep()

```
import asyncio
bot = commands.Bot('e!',intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
      

    if message.content.startswith('whats the meaning of life'):
        await message.channel.send(
            'The meaning of life is "freedom from suffering" through apatheia (Gr: απαθεια), that is, being objective and having "clear judgement", not indifference. - Wikipedia.'
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await message.channel.send(
            'There, someone just explained your life. Kind of depressing, isnt it?'
        )
```