# DiscordPY Bot Intents Also Just Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I am making a discord bot with python3, I am trying to do it, but it doesn't seem to be working, here is my code

```
import os
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents(534723950656))

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Pong!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

This is just a test of course, but when it runs correctly, no message is sent in the channel when I type !ping

I have tried changing permissions to admin and using discord.Intents.all() and .default(), neither have worked.
Sometimes when I run it, I get a Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 4013 error

Comment: Hi Jay and welcome to Stackoverflow. You might be interested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677).

Comment: Any reason you're using a number instead of just explicitly setting the intents? It's a lot harder to figure out what's going on like this, as opposed to just being able to read which intents you have enabled

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

It's exactly what [stijndcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13568999/stijndcl) said in their comment. Set the intents explicitly instead of using a number.

Also, make sure you have the necessary intents enabled on the Discord Developer Portal.