# Why does the discord command works only if the bot is included

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Hello everyone I am a beginner coder . I am making a discord bot about a gam system. for e.g
!win @name @name it will add point to the winner and deduct point from the loser. One thing is that when I do the command with other people it dosen't work. But if I do the command with !win @bot @name then it works only if the bot is included. Is there any solution. And is there any way for showing the points of all the people in the server. If so please provide some reference code.  Thanks!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()  # Load environment variables from .env file

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# Dictionary to store player points
player_points = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@bot.command()
async def win(ctx, winner: discord.Member, loser: discord.Member):
    if winner.id == loser.id:
        await ctx.send("You can't win against yourself!")
        return

    if winner.id not in player_points:
        player_points[winner.id] = 0
    if loser.id not in player_points:
        player_points[loser.id] = 0

    player_points[winner.id] += 1
    if loser.id in player_points and player_points[loser.id] > 0:
        player_points[loser.id] -= 0.5

    winner_embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Match Result",
        description=f"{winner.mention} has won against {loser.mention}!",
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )
    winner_embed.add_field(name="Points", value=f"{winner.mention}: {player_points[winner.id]}")
    await ctx.send(embed=winner_embed)

    loser_embed = discord.Embed(

        title="Match Result",
        description=f"{loser.mention} has lost against {winner.mention}!",
        color=discord.Color.red()
        )
    loser_embed.add_field(name="Points", value=f"{loser.mention}: {player_points[loser.id]}")
    await ctx.send(embed=loser_embed)


@bot.command()
async def draw(ctx, player1: discord.Member, player2: discord.Member):
    if player1.id == player2.id:
        await ctx.send("You can't draw with yourself!")
        return

    if player1.id not in player_points:
        player_points[player1.id] = 0
    if player2.id not in player_points:
        player_points[player2.id] = 0

    player_points[player1.id] += 0.5
    player_points[player2.id] += 0.5

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Match Result",
        description=f"{player1.mention} and {player2.mention} have drawn!",
        color=discord.Color.greyple()
    )
    embed.add_field(name="Points", value=f"{player1.mention}: {player_points[player1.id]}, {player2.mention}: {player_points[player2.id]}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def reset(ctx):
    player_points.clear()
    await ctx.send("Points have been reset.")



bot.run('NO')
```

I tried to check if the bot is in the command and return but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have enough intents for the gamble command except for one :
the `Intents.message_content` attribute

You used the default intents which includes all intents except `presences`, `members` and `message_content`. (Which explained in the discord.py documentation [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20intents#discord.Intents.default).)

To fix this, it's pretty simple, all you need is to add the `message_content` intent.

Which resulted to this

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
```

It should hopefully enable the specified intent and the bot should work as intended now. If it doesn't work, you should check if you have enabled the intents on the [Discord Developers Page](https://discord.com/developers/applications). It should be like this :

[image]