# How do I make my discord bot respond to when a specific user says anything?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make my discord bot say a phrase when a user says something but it isn't working. I am very new to discord.py. I know the user's id I want the bot to respond to.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    message = ctx.content.lower()
    print(message.author.id)
    if ctx.author.id == INSERT_ID:
        await ctx.channel.send(INSERT_PHRASE)
    return


client.run(INSERT_TOKEN)
```

It can grab the user's id just can't respond so I think it might be a syntax problem.

Comment: Hi @Moose, you should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need `message_content` intent for your client because this intent can let your bot to read messages from channels. You can change the line of code to this

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And don't forget to turn on the message content switch in your discord developer portal.
In your `on_message` event, there should not be context param involved.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id == the_specific_user_id_integer: 
    await message.channel.send("some msg")
    return
  
  # if not, maybe do sth else
```